# Can I use 2 tables in single stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure where I am using 2 tables to fetch data based on a condition but it is giving the error.

My SP is:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE select_notifications(IN datePosted DATETIME,IN recipientId INT,IN packageId INT,IN accountId INT)
BEGIN
 IF datePosted < NOW() THEN
  SELECT tn.subject_line,tn.message,tn.message_type FROM track_notifications AS tn WHERE tn.package_id=packageId AND tn.recipient_id=recipientId AND tn.account_id=accountId AND tn.date_posted = datePosted;
 ELSE IF datePosted > NOW()
  SELECT subject_line,message,message_type FROM track_notifications_new WHERE package_id=packageId AND recipient_id=recipientId AND account_id=accountId AND date_posted = datePosted;
 END IF;
END
END //
```

Mysql Error:

> The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
>   PROCEDURE `select_track_notifications`(IN `datePosted` DATETIME, IN
>   `recipientId` INT, IN `packageId` INT, IN `accountId` INT) NOT
>   DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN IF datePosted <
>   NOW() THEN SELECT tn.subject_line,tn.message,tn.message_type FROM
>   track_notifications AS tn WHERE tn.package_id=packageId AND
>   tn.recipient_id=recipientId AND tn.account_id=accountId AND
>   tn.date_posted = datePosted; ELSE IF datePosted > NOW() THEN SELECT
>   subject_line,message,message_type FROM track_notifications_new WHERE
>   package_id=packageId AND recipient_id=recipientId AND
>   account_id=accountId AND date_posted = datePosted; END IF; END"

Comment: You just forgot the `THEN` after the `ELSE IF` condition...

Comment: I already tried that too but got the same error thats why I have removed after that error

Comment: And what is this error of yours?

Comment: updated my question please check it once.

Comment: Every if must have a then and an end if (your else if doesn't) and you may not be setting delimiters https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Ah, yeah, you wrote `ELSE IF` instead of  `ELSEIF`... So use `ELSEIF ... THEN`.

Comment: EDIT your question to add complete SQL statement you are using to create the stored procedure.

Comment: updated the question, check it once. @Madhur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have an extra `END` at the end of your statement.
- Also, you will need to reset the Delimiter to `;` at the end.
- Else if syntax is `ELSEIF .... THEN` (no space between ELSE and IF).
- Also, I think you may need to use [`SELECT .. INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) clause to store the results of your select query into variables  (on which you will do further actions).

Try the following instead:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS select_notifications //
CREATE PROCEDURE select_notifications(IN datePosted DATETIME,
                                      IN recipientId INT,
                                      IN packageId INT,
                                      IN accountId INT)
BEGIN
 IF datePosted < NOW() THEN
  SELECT tn.subject_line,
         tn.message,
         tn.message_type 
  FROM track_notifications AS tn 
  WHERE tn.package_id=packageId AND 
        tn.recipient_id=recipientId AND 
        tn.account_id=accountId AND 
        tn.date_posted = datePosted;

 ELSEIF datePosted > NOW() THEN 
  SELECT subject_line,
         message,
         message_type 
  FROM track_notifications_new 
  WHERE package_id=packageId AND 
        recipient_id=recipientId AND 
        account_id=accountId AND 
        date_posted = datePosted;
 END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @prasadchinthala Please do read about `select .. into` (link in the answer) - you will need it in your SP.

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure hello (
     @id int,
     @student_name varchar(50),
     @student_address varchar(100)
)
 AS
 BEGIN
   insert into studentResult
    (id,
    student_name,
    student_address)

 values (
    @id,
    @student_name,
    @student_address
  )
end
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.